# PlayerHealth attribute not changing in if statement while PlayerClass is

Tags: c#

I made an object for the player to have attributes like health and what class the player is going to be. When I attempt to change the health property inside of an if statement it does not change

Ive tried reassigning the value and adding to the original value

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello What is your name?");

            Player player = new Player("", "", 0);
            player.Name = Console.ReadLine();
            string playerName = player.Name;

            Console.WriteLine($"Welcome {playerName} to my game. It's a simple text based adventure game");

            Console.WriteLine("What class would you like to be?");

            player.PlayerClass = Console.ReadLine();
            string sPlayerClass = player.PlayerClass;

            if (sPlayerClass.Contains("warrior"))
            {
                player.PlayerClass = "worrior";
                player.Health = player.Health + 20;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(player.Health);
            Console.WriteLine(player.PlayerClass);
```

this is from the main class

and this is from the player class

```
public class Player
{

    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string PlayerClass{get; set;}
    public int Health{get; set;}

    public Player(string name, string playerClass, int health)
    {   
        Name = name;
        PlayerClass = playerClass;
        Health = health;
    }
}
```

expected: Console.Writeline(player.Health) = 20

actual: Console.Writeline(player.Health) = 0

Comment: Are you sure that the if condition is evaluating to `true`? You can use the debugger to put a break point on it and see if that's the case.

Comment: @NatPongjardenlarp It's assigned a value just three lines up.  `player.PlayerClass = Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: 'warrior' is different than 'worrior'

Comment: question has been solved thanks to Antonio Veneroso Contreas

Answer (score 0):

Need to change worrior to warrior credit goes to Antonio Veneroso Contreas